# mouseover/hover help in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click, mouse

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Vulcun Jackpot Autoclicker
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.35
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://vulcun.com/user/jackpot
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function enterContest() {
$('#submit-wager').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
       console.log("button disabled: skipped");
       return;
    }

    console.log(this);
    this.click();
    console.log("Button clicked");

});
}

setInterval(enterContest, 30000);
```

This code is not mine, just to make it clear. The code does work, however I want to add to it. The `this.click();` in line 19 does its job but I want to add something along the lines, and before it, a thing that resembles a `this.hover();` or a `this.mouseover();` I am new to this. The object that is being clicked need to recognize that the mouse is hovering over it before it can be clicked. Before I would have to put my actual mouse on the object, however I want the process to proceed without me needing to use my actual mouse. I found out that `this.hover();` and `this.mouseover();` are not proper functions. So what is the proper function or code? Basically I want to make a virtual mouse so the object thinks it is being touched by my real mouse, but it's not.

edit: fixed version:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Vulcun Jackpot Autoclickerfix
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.35
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://vulcun.com/user/jackpot
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function enterContest() {
$('#submit-wager').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
      console.log("button disabled: skipped");
       //return;
    }else{
        $(this).trigger('mouseover').trigger('click').trigger('mouseleave');
    }
});
}
$('#submit-wager').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Input Pressed');
});
$('#submit-wager').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).addClass('addThisClass');
    console.log('touch');
});
$('#submit-wager').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('addThisClass');
});

setInterval(enterContest, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the current element in your `each` method(`$(this)`). Change `this.click();` to `$(this).click();`. As @Mohamed-Yousef said the ID must be unique. According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute
>
> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

```
function enterContest() {
$('#submit-wager').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
       console.log("button disabled: skipped");
       return;
    }

    console.log($(this));
    $(this).click();
    console.log("Button clicked");

});
}

setInterval(enterContest, 30000);
```

Comment: i get the fixes, but i don't get what the deal is with the ID, @Mohamed-Yousef said to use "$('.submit-wager').each(function() { " but it did not work. You say it need to be modified but when i look at your code it stays the same. I'm lost here.

Comment: @AAcat I mean This user(@Mohamed-Yousef) mentions your problem too.

Comment: The thing is, i don't know what that problem is. I never worked with jQuery before. you say the ID has a problem, but i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @AAcat I think [this link can be helpful](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

Comment: ahh i see, thanks. Btw the webiste that this userscript is used for says that its a ID. so i have to keep it as a "#" sign.

Comment: Great. ID `"#"` ,  Class `"."`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you loop through `#submit-wager` and you must know  (ID must be unique) so change `id="submit-wager"`  to `class="submit-wager"` and loop through them

```
$('.submit-wager').each(function() {
```

2nd: for trigger `mouseover` you can use

```
$(this).trigger('mouseover');
```

[**Demo to how to deal with this**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zLxa0sam/)

Comment: I tried your code, it did not work. Turns out the ID is on the website, and is not related to the physical userscript. (or at least that's what i theorize) I have fixed your code, big thanks btw, to work.

Comment: @AAcat by change my code .submit-wager to #submit-wager  it will select just the first element with id="submit-wager" even you use .each() it will not loop through the same Ids .. cause you shouldn't have more than one element with same id .. Good Luck :) .. but wait we can find another solution for that .. can you post a simple html code with form or submit button on it??

Comment: i mean, it works now. so that's good right? anyways thanks for all the support. My teachers can't even solve this one.